# How to submit the form using javascript with "this"

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

Is there any way to submit the current form in which i have the href link like this

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="this.submit();">Save</a>
```

I want to use same code evrywhere so i can't use any id or class

Comment: Why do you want to do this ? It is a good practice to put your code in separate javascript file. Is there any reason you could not separate the markup from the script ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Submit form using `this.form.submit()`

i.e in your case it will be like

```
<a href="#" onclick="this.form.submit();">Save</a>
```

But it highly recommended to use form name

otherwise if you are comfortable using jquery you can also use jquery [**closest**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function

```
$(field).closest("form").submit();
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
<a href="javascript:;"onclick="document.forms.<formname>.submit();">Save</a>
```

Actually it seems to work when `<formname>` is replaced with the form's id also.

Althoughy I would strongly recommend you research the practice known as [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="" onclick="!function(a){while(a&&a.nodeName!="FORM")a=a.parentNode;if(a)a.submit();}(this);"></a>
```

Comment: The correct code is: `<a href="" onclick="!function(a){while(a&&a.nodeName!='FORM')a=a.parentNode;if(a)a.submit();}(this);"></a>`.

Answer (score 1):

I use this solution for unknown form name:

```
function submitForm(originator)
{
    var pN=originator.parentNode;
    while (true)
    {
        if (pN&&pN.nodeName=='FORM')
        {
            pN.submit();
            break;
        }
        pN=pN.parentNode;
    }
}
```

and now on any document's object event we can use this function:

```
<div onclick="doSomething();submitForm(this)">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have `n` number of forms on your page. You can submit `i+1`th form by using:

```
document.forms[i].submit();
```

So if you have just one, and want to submit on link click,

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

should be your `onclick` attribute's value

Comment: but then i need to diff code for every href. I have around 30 files and i am replacing the submit button with href with shell script

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<a href="" onkeypress="submit(this.form)"/>
<script>
    function submit(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use more tricky way.
make your button looks like `<a href>`

`<button type="submit" style="background-color: transparent!important;border: none;padding: 0!important;color: #3c8dbc;cursor: pointer;box-sizing: border-box;">MY LINK BUTTON</button>`